# nginx https ip address to domain redirect

Tags: nginx, url, redirect

My website is pretty messed up: it shows up as https://31.220.108.250/ in the google search results (https, not http). I want to redirect this to my domain (mosachi.ga), but when I couldn't figure out how to redirect https to my domain (I could only figure out how to redirect http). Here is my current nginx config file:

```
# Catchall configuration - redir to the domain for bare and invalid domain requests
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://mosachi.ga$request_uri;
}

# HTTP handler to redirect to HTTPS for mosachi.ga
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  mosachi.ga;
  return 301 https://mosachi.ga$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS for mosachi.ga
server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  mosachi.ga;

  ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mosachi.ga/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mosachi.ga/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your nginx file formate as below! and check whether it is working or not?

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root your_root_folder_path;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mosachi.ga/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mosachi.ga/privkey.pem;
    server_name mosachi.ga www.mosachi.ga;

    location / {

            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name mosachi.ga;
return 301 https://mosachi.ga$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, https://31.220.108.250 says invalid certificate rather than redirect on curl

Comment: @JasonCheng Please verify your certificate, from where you download the SSL?